# compare an integer with multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, callback, compare

I have below array and a number `$num`, i am trying to check if `$num` is equal to or in range of `from` and `to` of each element. if condition true than corresponding or key of that array should be returned with stopping the further comparison. i am able to achieve this using `array_walk`, but not able to halt further comparison

```
Array
(
    [_1395216158966_966] => Array
        (
            [from] => 1
            [to] => 3
            [rate] => 10
        )

    [_1395216219094_94] => Array
        (
            [from] => 3
            [to] => 6
            [rate] => 15
        )

    [_1395216219662_662] => Array
        (
            [from] => 6
            [to] => 9
            [rate] => 20
        )

)
```

**current code**

```
array_walk($data, array($this, 'CalculateWeightCharge'), $weight)

public function CalculateWeightCharge($data, $needle, $num)
    {

        if($num >= $data['from'] && $num <= $data['to']){
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have to use `array_filter`

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: @AlmaDo check the current code

Comment: @hindmost your suggestion is good, but how will i pass the number???

Comment: @DepH By `use` construct (http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function fn($numbers, $num)
{
    foreach($numbers as $key=>$val)
    {
         if($num >= $val["from"] && $num <= $val["to"])
         {
            return $key;
         }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: How is this any different to Andrey Mischenko's answer?

Comment: I was writing my own answer. I did not see what he posted

Comment: I notice that you have included each end of the range as well, so yours is actually correct.

Comment: yeah, it should be >= and <= as in question user want to check $num is equal to or in range of from and to

Answer (score 2):

```
function compare($array, $num) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($num >= $value['from'] && $num <= $value['to']) // any condition here
            return $key;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code for checking if `$num` is in each of ranges in `$array` array:

```
$result = array_filter($array, function ($v) use($num) {
    return $num >= $v['from'] && $num <= $v['to'];
})
if (count($result) == count($array)) echo 'TRUE';
```

Comment: But `array_filter` "Iterates over _each_ value in the array" http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php whereas the question is about stopping once a match has been found.

Comment: @Tom Fenech That's right. So OP has to use loop (as in earlier answer) if he want such efficiency.

Comment: That's right, so your answer doesn't answer the question!